# Problem with using sets and issubset in Python

Tags: python, set, tuples, subset

I'm not clear about how my sets needs to be written. The answer I'm getting is False, which means I'm using the issubset type wrong or my sets are not written correctly.

```
some_cords = {(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)}
line_cords = {((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)), ((1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)), ((2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)),
              ((2, 4), (2, 3), (2, 2))}    

print(some_cords.issubset(line_cords))
print(any(some_cords in k for k in line_cords))

>>False
>>False
```

I've tried these two methods but why they're False, I'm not sure. I've also tried writing some_cords and line_cords as tuples rather than sets, i.e.
some_cords = ((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)) but I'm getting the same result. I'm running Python 3.10 in IntelliJ IDE. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `some_cords` is a set of coordinates. `line_cords` is a set of tuples of coordinates. The values are not comparable/equal.

Comment: I wrote them this way: 
some_cords = {((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2))}
line_cords = ((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)), ((1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)), ((2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)), \
              ((2, 4), (2, 3), (2, 2))

Comment: While 3 points can define a line (though 2 is sufficient), storing 3 points is not a good way to *represent* a line. Given any two points on a line, you can compute a unique 2-dimensional value that identifies the line. That value could be the slope and the y-intercept, the slope and the x-intercept, the x- and y-intercepts, the angle with respect to an axis and a distance from the origin, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As written, `some_cords` is a set with 3 elements, each one is a tuple: `(1, 2)`, `(2, 2)` and `(3, 2)`. On the other hand, `line_cords` is a set of 4 tuples, each tuple being a tuple of length 3.

Adding parenthesis around the tuples of `some_cords` will turn it into a set with one element similar to the ones of `line_cords`:

```
some_cords = {((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2))}
```

and the first test will return `True`

As for the second test (using `in`), `some_cords` is a `set`, and each element of `line_cords` is a tuple, so it will always return `False`. This test would be OK if `some_cords` was a tuple: you can achieve this removing the braces, but then you can not use `issubset`.